# How to redirect to login page on session time of any of the session created on multiple pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed a project having multiple .aspx pages. I am making use of many sessions in almost all the pages. If any of the session gets expire the application is throwing error. I dont want to check the session expiration on all the pages for all the session that i have created. Can anyone suggest me how can i solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Never used but I think `Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)` method of `Global.asax` file can be used for this purpose.

Another solution can be checking the session status at `Site.Master` page of your project. Your other pages must use this page as their master page.

Comment: not used for exactly this, but the event will fire when a session ends so you can gracefully handle it rather than ysod when you access a non-existant session variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not checking if a session variable value actually exists or not, that can break your applications in various scenarios. If your application gets recycled (or web.config updates) can kill the session variables if you are using InProc (memory). There is no real better way to handle all scenarios apart from checking to see if the variable actually exists in session before using it. That is the best practice. It might be worth adding that condition if you don't want unexpected crashes.

You could use the session_end event to repopulate all your variables but thats not break proof.